# Create extra tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on this project, and i have this bar that will have tabs filled in it dynamically. What i want to do is have a (+) image that appears whenever the bar is full, and when the user clicks on it, the rest of the tabs will appear. Something like what facebook have in the profile page to add a new tab.

Anyone knows an easy way of doing it ??

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: Not really, what I want is when the first row is full, a (+) sign or any other image i choose to appear, and whatever new tabs are added, they wont appear unless i click the (+) or the image ... kind of a drop down menu with the tabs that do not have a space in the bar ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/n2gCP/1/